# Django template variables, RequestContext, and context processors

Tags: django, django-templates

**EDIT**
I am building a messaging part of a website but for some reason I just noticed that the function will not actually show the messages in the template. Here is the function and template for the inbox page:

```
def show_inbox(request):
u = request.user
messages = Message.objects.filter(to_user=u)
context = RequestContext(request,{'messages':messages})
return render_to_response('users/messaging/inbox.html',context_instance=context)

<table class="table-list" cellspacing="0">
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Recieved at</th>
            <th>Read</th>
            <th>Replied</th>
            {% if not messages %}
                <tr><td class="left">No messages</td></tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            <tr class="{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}even{% else %}odd{% endif %}">
                <td class="left largetd">
                    <a href="{{ message.from_user.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ message.from_user.profile_pic }}" class="small-pic" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="{{ message.get_absolute_url }}">{{ message.message_subject }}</a>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                         <span class="small-text italics">{{ message.message_date_time }}</span> 
                </td>
                <td class="smalltd text-center">{{ message.message_is_read }}</td>
                <td class="smalltd text-center"></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

Comment: I´m not sure I get your problem. Can you explain yourself a little more?

Comment: Sure. On the inbox page where all the messages show up, it for some reason isnt getting the message variable passed into the template. as from what I posted, the template always renders "No messages". And I cant seem to find why the messages arent showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have checked that the *messages* variable actually has messages before you call render_to_response() right? Otherwise, view-source on the resulting HTML and see if anything is there. You are missing the <**tr**> tag around your header cells.

Also, try calling render_to_response a little differently.

```
return render_to_response('users/messaging/inbox.html', {'messages': messages})
```

By default, the template will be rendered using a *Context* instance that is filled with values from the provided dictionary. Therefore you can call it in this simpler form. You aren't using any *request* variables in the view templates so you don't need the RequestContext, which uses [context processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) to provide your template with additional information pulled from the request.

@fceruti is correct that you had a collision with [django.contrib.messages](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages). When you used RequestContext, Django cycled through your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS (declared in the settings.py file) to provide more variables for your template. Specifically 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages' added a *messages* variable, which overwrote your own. Change the name of your variable and you'd be fine.

> Each processor is applied in order.
>   That means, if one processor adds a
>   variable to the context and a second
>   processor adds a variable with the
>   same name, the second will override
>   the first.

Comment: Well that worked, but why would it not work inside RequestContext i wonder.. Hmmm.. weird. Thanks tho! I never thought about trying that

Comment: This seems to be the problem. You either change the variable name or remove 'django.contrib.messages' from installed apps. "messages" is beeing used by the messaging framework.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. And it's simpler code! Will update answer with an attempted explanation.

Comment: Wow.. LOL so thats what it was? Theres a lot more I need to know about this framework then. I thought I knew a descent amount but Ive only been working with it for about a month. But thanks for the heads up. Now I know if everything seems totally correct, that it could be another issue like this! Thanks!